# Creating icon on Click is too slow

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I want to create cross on the position of the cursor on click and then fade out
but It's working only when I wait for a moment after I click and I don't know why

here`s the code

```
body = document.querySelector('body');

function Crossing(e) {
       this.newCross = document.createElement('i');
       this.newCross.className = 'fas fa-times';
       this.newCross.style.position = 'absolute';
       this.newCross.style.left = e.clientX - 10 + 'px';
       this.newCross.style.top = e.clientY - 14 + 'px';
       this.newCross.style.fontSize = '30px';
       this.newCross.style.opacity = '100%';
       this.newCross.style.transition = 'all 1s ease-out';
       body.appendChild(this.newCross);
       this.timeout1 = setTimeout(() => this.newCross.style.opacity = '0%', 1);
       this.timeout2 = setTimeout(() => this.newCross.remove(), 1000);
   } 

   window.addEventListener('click', () => {
       new Crossing(e);
   });
```

This is just part of the actual code but only this part has something to do with creating icon

Comment: As per https://stackoverflow.com/a/28443567/7003720, there will be a period in which the element hasn't been drawn to the page, and in your case it appears to be greater than 1ms. Instead of trying to guess the timing in `setTimeout`, you can use `requestAnimationFrame` with the same callback to set the opacity to 0%.

Comment: Actually, it looks like `requestAnimationFrame` can also cause the same issue, so unfortunately you'll have to experiment to find an acceptable initial delay.